# How to see binding value on running query mysql?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

When I issue "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" query to debug and tuning slow query, running SQL query show for me but the Prepared Statements query contains "?".

For example: "SELECT * FROM users where id=?"

How can I find out what value binding on "?" placeholder?

Comment: For debugging i have installed https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, in this bar you can see all queries, and much more.

Comment: But, my service is in production now, and MySQL is on high load with many different queries, I try to explain the query and find the best index to use.

Comment: Do you log the query using DB::listen(function($sql) { ... })? you can log the bindings too using $sql->bindings

Comment: I'm not sure if the value of "?" is important in determining best index. I think in the example above, having index over `id` probably will improve the query speed and probably either `=?` or `="?"`..